# How do I setup Individual Column color for each Column (HighStock/HighChart)

Tags: highcharts

[Please have a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8GL/)

I am trying to create a column chart using Highstock. I want to specify the color for each individual column. I tried everything I can but couldn't get it to work.

Can someone advise please?

Thanks a lot

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=range.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'columnrange'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 2
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Temperature variation by day'
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: data
        }]

    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Seems like when marker is used `color` attribute of point is ignored by highcharts. Just put the `color` option inside `marker` if you set the `marker` attribute of the point. If you don't set the marker, just set color attribute as you already did in your example.

Here is a working example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8GL/

Answer (score 0):

In case when you would like to change color of column, you should set color parameter.

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            color:'red'
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8GL/1/